# Dynamic menu and role permission in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

Hello Guyzz i am new in codeigniter, and i need help in role base login in system,
i have two table 1st in Category and 2nd is user_reg,

In 2nd table category_id stored like this 1,2,3 so is it Possible to fetch this id?

Please Give me suggestion and solution i am new in CI,
give me some guidance about dynamic menu and role based login access

Category:[image]

User:
[image]

Comment: create a `m:n` - `user_category` table because this is simply a pain, if you save your relations as a comma separated string..., nevertheless a possible solution could be the use of `find_in_set` take a look here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Comment: "category_id stored like this 1,2,3" Don't do that. See [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). You want a [join table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity).

Comment: then how to join, i have id like this 1,2,3 @AlexHowansky

Comment: "then how to join" Maybe read the links I posted?

Comment: ok i will read that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

database tables example :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` text NOT NULL,
  `create_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `username`, `password`, `create_at`) VALUES
(1, 'ali', 'qorbani', 'aliqorbani', '63bed66f3d9dcd13440490d90738f816', '2018-07-28 08:34:01'),
(2, 'mohammad', 'ahmadi', 'mohammad', '316946a88ad51d75465c4c0b1e4a066a', '2018-07-28 08:34:01');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_groups` (
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `create_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`group_id`),
  KEY `group_id` (`group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `user_groups` (`group_id`, `group_name`, `create_at`) VALUES
(1, 'superadmin', '2018-07-28 08:35:56'),
(2, 'admin', '2018-07-28 08:35:56'),
(3, 'moderator', '2018-07-28 08:36:12'),
(4, 'customer', '2018-07-28 08:36:12');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_roles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `group_id` (`group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `user_roles`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `user_roles_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `user_roles_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `user_groups` (`group_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;
```

codes for your **model** will be like this.

//User_model

```
public function add($data){
    $this->db->insert('users',$data);
    return true;
}
public function update($data,$id){
    $this->db->where('user_id',$id);
    $this->db->update('users',$data);
    return true;
}

public function add_user_roles($user_id,$roles = array()){
    $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);
    $this->db->delete('user_roles');
    foreach ($roles as $role){
        $this->db->insert('user_roles',['user_id'=>$user_id,'group_id'=>$role]);
    }
    return true;
}
```

and the example for your **controller** **Edit** method will be like this snippet:

```
//Users controller
public function edit($user_id){
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $data_view['user'] = $this->User_model->get_user($user_id);
        $this->load->view('user_edit',$data_view);
    }else{
    $first_name = $this->input->post('first_name');
    $last_name = $this->input->post('last_name');
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));
    $user_roles = $this->input->post('roles');
    $data_user_update = array(
        'first_name'    =>  $first_name, 
        'last_name'     =>  $last_name, 
        'username'      =>  $username, 
        'password'      =>  $password
    );
    $this->User_model->add_user_roles$user_id,$user_roles);
    $this->User_model->update($data_user_update,$user_id);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success','user updated correctly');
    redirect('users/edit/'.$user_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: another thing i forgot is view. 
use multiple checkbox with value of group_ids (you can also get them from database and pass it as array to your view then use `foreach($roles as $key=>$value)` loop an inside that use `form_checkbox($value,$key)`

Answer (score 1):

Never ever use this way anymore! 
create 2 different tables (users,user_groups). add a column to user table `group_id` and then use `join` function to get theme 
for more information see [this link](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#id1)

if you can't figure out please post your table data here and i'll help you :-)

Answer (score 1):

here is my (post,post_tax,post_tax_relation) tables screenshot. i think it can help you wat you need. 
remember on `create`,`update` users you must update relation table (I mean delete all relation refer to that user and create new ones on every update).
[image: Posts table - (use it as your user table)]

[image: taxonomies - use it as your **User Groups**]

[image: relations - for collect all user permission levels]

Comment: what is post_author in 1st table?